# Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Tags: class, object, int, stdclass

problem is "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int"

this is code:

```
$user = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$user_name'"));
if($user) == 0){
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching object from database not a string or int
so need have acces metchod to field in your class, and a field then for example check can be done by:

```
if ($user->user_id === null )

or

if ($user->{'user.id'} == null )

if there are problems with `user.id`
```